# publish jar files with sbt (3rd party)

Tags: scala, sbt

Hello I have 5 jar files and tried to publish them to a local repository with sbt.
But when I place them in unmanagedBase directory like `lib/` they won't get copied with `publishLocal`. Is there an easy way to include them in the publishing process?

Currently maven has a similar solution here:
http://maven.apache.org/guides/mini/guide-3rd-party-jars-local.html

Answer (score 4, accepted):

One option is to define a subproject for each jar that you want published.  Have your main project depend on each.  Give each subproject an appropriate `name`, `version`, and `organization`.  For each subproject, put its jar somewhere not on the classpath and make the output of `packageBin` be that jar.

For example (sbt 0.13 build.sbt),

```
lazy val main = project.dependsOn(subA)

lazy val subA = project.settings(
   name := "third-party",
   organization := "org.example",
   version := "1.4",
   packageBin in Compile := baseDirectory.value / "bin" / "third-party.jar",
   // if there aren't doc/src jars use the following to
   //   avoid publishing empty jars locally
   // otherwise, define packageDoc/packageSrc like packageBin 
   publishArtifact in packageDoc := false,
   publishArtifact in packageSrc := false,
   // tell sbt to put the jar on main's classpath
   //   and not the (empty) class directory
   exportJars := true,
   // set this to not add _<scalaBinaryVersion> to the name
   crossPaths := true
)
```

This approach allows you to change the jar in `subA/bin/third-party.jar` and have it be used immediately and a subsequent `publishLocal` will publish it locally.

If you prefer separately publishing it locally, so that it isn't part of the project, define `subA` as a standalone project instead.

Comment: Is there a way to publish multiple jars?

Comment: I'm getting 'java.lang.RuntimeException: Repository for publishing is not specified'

Comment: @Havnar Correct, defining where to publish to is not covered in this answer. Fortunately, that's the easy part.