# How to publish multiple jar files to repository sbt

Tags: scala, build, sbt, nexus, publishing

I have multi module project and using Build.scala to build.
 I am using nexus repository to publish.
Project structure is like 
NLP
Core
Project1
Project2
 
Now say Project1 depends on Core and Project2 depends on Core and Project1 and lastly main project has dependency on all these jars. 
When I do **publishTo** nlp.jar and pom.xml gets published to repository 
 
 
I also would like to publish jars from other projects as well so those are available to consumer project. 
 However somehow I am able to publish only nlp.jar and other projects jar and pom files are not getting published.

I tried to even look at following link however that did not help.
[publish jar files with sbt (3rd party)](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/19290812/publish-jar-files-with-sbt-3rd-party)

Thanks for help in advance.

Comment: Do these different projects have different directories or are they all at the root, i.e. `project.in(file("."))`?

Comment: Build.scala will not be an option when SBT gets to version 1.0. So best to put the build in build.sbt.